# Error running Context texexec on Mac OSX 10.10, Ruby 2.2.0 Stable

Tags: errors, context-mkii

When I try to run texexec on my context file I get the following error:

```
texexec va.ctx
/Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/base/ctx.rb:120:in `manipulate': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/base/tex.rb:1729:in `processfile'
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/base/tex.rb:1081:in `block (2 levels) in processtex'
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/base/tex.rb:1071:in `timedrun'
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/base/tex.rb:1080:in `block in processtex'
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/base/tex.rb:1077:in `each'
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/base/tex.rb:1077:in `processtex'
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/texexec.rb:66:in `process'
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/texexec.rb:56:in `main'
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/base/switch.rb:135:in `execute'
    from /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/scripts/context/ruby/texexec.rb:791:in `<main>'
```

Here are the relevant software versions:

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.61
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /Users/davidsmith/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2015.02.03 23:55

ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

I have no real idea about how to go about solving this problem. I have tried both with the texlive version (0.60) and the most recent (0.61).

The document I am trying to compile is in UTF8 and has some accented characters.

-- UPDATE --

Anything with any accented character fails like this. E.g. -

```
\startmode[*mkii]
  \enableregime[utf-8]  
  \setupcolors[state=start]
\stopmode

% Enable hyperlinks
\setupinteraction[state=start, color=middleblue]

\setuppapersize [letter][letter]

\setuplayout    [width=middle,  backspace=1.5in, cutspace=1.5in,
                 height=middle, topspace=0.75in, bottomspace=0.75in]
\starttext
á
\stoptext
```

Comment: After a little more poking around, it seems that a MWE is anything with an accented character! Example added above.

Comment: The file type `.ctx` is used for XML preprocessing files with `texexec`. You either have to rename your file to `.tex` or call `context` instead of `texexec`.

Comment: Any particular reason you are using MkII (pdftex based format) instead of MkIV (luatex based format)?

Comment: @DG' This solved my problem. How silly of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The file type `.ctx` is used for XML preprocessing files with `texexec`](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/xmanipulate.pdf). You either have to rename your file to `.tex` or call `context` instead of `texexec`.